# Making a layer modular/extensible in Java

Tags: java, extensible

I'm new in the Java world and struggle a little bit with my application. I divided my application into several layers (UI, controller, ...). The bottom layer is responsible for gathering data from sensors.

My goal is to make this layer extensible, such that external users/programmers could easily add new sensors in it.

Do I only have to separate each sensor in a distinct class or is there any other solution for it?

My apologies if it's a 'weird' question, I'm just a newbie :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you are building is a framework.  The sensor code would follow the Hollywood Principle: "don't call me, I'll call you"

This is achieved by applying the Dependency Inversion Principle.

You create an interface Sensor.java:

```
public interface Sensor {
    Reading getReading();
}
```

And a Reading.java (making this general is an Open Closed Principle challenge related to how much generality you need from sensor data structures):

```
public final class Reading {
}
```

And a a SensorReader.java:

```
public final class SensorReader {
    private final Iterable<Sensor> sensors;
    public SensorReader(Iterable<Sensor> sensors) {
        this.sensors = sensors;
    }
    public void readSensors() {
        for (Sensor sensor : sensors) {
            Reading reading = sensor.getReading();
            // so stuff with reading
        }
    }
}
```

Everything above here is framework, everything past here is application/client code.

And a MotorEncoder.java:

```
final class MotorEncoder implements Sensor {
    @Override
    public Reading getReading() {
        // do stuff to actually read motor encoder
        return new Reading();
    }
}
```

And an Application.java:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public final class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sensor sensor = new MotorEncoder();
        SensorReader sensorReader = new SensorReader(Arrays.asList(sensor));
        sensorReader.readSensors();
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your fast reply! I think building a framework will be the solution for my problem. Nevertheless, I will have to analyse the Dependency Inversion Principle because it is a little bit unclear for me now.

Comment: @VoyageMoh best resource I know of for that are  Clean Code book and the Clean Coders video series by Robert C. Martin (aka Uncle Bob). https://cleancoders.com/

Comment: May I just ask you what the goal is of SensorReader.java class? And what if I make a second MotorEncoder object in the Application.java class. I should actually make a list of all the sensors and give it to the SensorReader constructor?

Comment: @VoyageMoh the SensorReader class is the framework or container that executes your pluggable Sensor code. You are right: in any given configuration you or your framework clients would construct a main function that hands the List of Sensors to the SensorReader constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom layer can have `List<Gatherer> gatherers` variable. Gatherer should be interface with methods important for the bottom layer.

Anyone can then create its own Gatherer and register it to your layer.

The bottom layer is responsible for executing gatherers, registering/removing them etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many mechanisms. For example Spring. You can define beans and include them during runtime (put in a folder), but the beans must implement some well defined interfaces.

Another solution would be to use some design patterns such as

[Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

[Template method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)